# как оставить только букву и число из текста?

Tags: javascript

```
let text = 'some my text with this code a23232 and another text'
```

мне нужно чтобы итоговый результат был таким

```
let text = 'a23232'
```

можно оставить только цифры и после добавить букву а

```
let text = text.replace(/\D+/g,"");
```

но мне не очень нравится, хочется более универсального варианта.
можно сделать через цикл, создать массив через split(' ') и через for() искать тот что больше подходит, но это длинная функция.

Comment: `text.match(/[a-z]\d+/i)[0]`

Comment: спасибо большое )

Comment: теперь проблема если нет такого кода в тексте то ругается на [0]

Comment: Попробуйте сами это решить. не все же мне за вас делать)